# how to create a file and pass parameters in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I create a plugin folder in wordpress called my-game. my code work perfectly in the old fashion way by calling add_action and other rules. the problem is that I don't want to call my code by registering it.I want to have a link in my sidebar ("index.php?action=game") which will get the content of game.php in my-game plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This woudln't be a nice way to do this but, can you add this in your function.php ?

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action']=='game')) {
    include(PATH_TO_GAME);
    exit();
}
```

I think the better way to do this is by adding a function in function.php to do what you want:

```
function MY_FUNCTION() {
    include(PATH_TO_GAME);
    exit();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_MY_FUNCTION', 'MY_FUNCTION');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_MY_FUNCTION', 'MY_FUNCTION');//for users that are not logged in
```

and then call it that way

```
$url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php').'?action=MY_FUNCTION';
```

Comment: I',m going to try it. isn't it better to write all the code in function.php from scratch?

Comment: Yes, or write a plugin for it